# Drush not connecting to site's settings.php

Tags: drush, configuration

When I run `drush --debug status` in the docroot of my Drupal site, I get the following message:

```
[user@computer]$ drush --debug status
Phar detected. Proceeding to drush_main().
Loading drushrc "/home/user/.drush/drushrc.php" into "home.drush"[bootstrap]
scope. [0.02 sec, 3.54 MB]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.14-commandfiles-removed    [debug]
[0.03 sec, 3.59 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.28 sec, 9.55 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Trying to bootstrap as far as we can. [0.28 sec, 9.56 MB]                [debug]
Found command: core-status (commandfile=core) [0.28 sec, 9.56 MB]    [bootstrap]
Loading outputformat engine. [0.28 sec, 9.56 MB]                        [notice]
Calling hook drush_core_status [0.29 sec, 9.85 MB]                       [debug]
Returned from hook drush_core_status [0.38 sec, 9.86 MB]        
         [debug]
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php.ini /home/user/.drush/drush.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush
 Drush version          :  8.1.14
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :  /home/user/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php
Command dispatch complete [x.xx sec, x.xx MB]                           [notice]
```

As you may see in that output, "PHP Configuration" has two entries where as "Drush configuration" has none. And that one of the entries for "PHP Configuration" looks like the entry that should be in "Drush configuration".

I did run it within the docroot of Drupal. And I have even tried in sites/default. Plus, I have even tried my aliases and none of them are working. This all worked before though with another Drupal site. It just stopped working after I transferred the Drupal files from one server to another. I thought my permissions were correct but they don't look correct. Plus I have even tried adding --uri and --root to Drush and that didn't work either. For the transfer I used rsync options `avzp`.

`drush -d pm-info` give's the following:

```
[user@computer]$ drush -d pm-info
Phar detected. Proceeding to drush_main().
Loading drushrc "/home/user/.drush/drushrc.php" into "home.drush"[bootstrap]
scope. [0.02 sec, 3.54 MB]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.14-commandfiles-removed    [debug] [0.03 sec, 3.59 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.27 sec, 9.55 MB]                                              [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.28 sec, 9.56 MB]                              [bootstrap]
Command pm-info needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need[error]
to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this
command. [0.28 sec, 9.56 MB]
The drush command 'pm-info' could not be executed. [0.28 sec, 9.56   [error]
MB]
```

Comment: You aren't running Drush in the Drupal root for sure. Check again and if you don't get it to work, edit your question with directory info.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but have not provided the exact directories used.

Comment: Are you sure 110% that the files have been transferred correctly? You should at least get the Drupal version if you are inside the Drupal root. Try a more interesting command - `drush -d pm-info` for example.

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: I'm able to access the site through the web interface and everything looks fine

Comment: "needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command". Are you 110% sure that the files have been transferred correctly. And are you sure that the site you are accessing in the browser is the same that you are running Drush in? Really sure.

Comment: Yep, I only have one directory in my /www/ directory that has files for serving a web page. The Drupal files are located in the directory name as it was with the previous site which had `drush status` was working. So that directory must be what's getting used. Plus phpinfo() works when adding it to index.php

Comment: Sorry, if you are 110% sure all files are present and you can't share any info about the directory structure and so on, I can't help you. PS! Your Drush is outdated, but likely not related to this issue.

Comment: I have the following in my docroot: `includes, modules, profiles, sites, temp, favicon.ico, index.php, install.php` and some other directories and files that I think is used by another application.

Comment: I assume this is a Drupal 7 installation? (You should have tagged the question with 7 and I should have asked about this in the beginning.) If it is D7, Drush 8.1.14 checks for the presence of `modules/field/field.module` to validate the root. Is that file present and readable? If this is a dead-end too, I'm giving up. It's too time consuming. (The best solution is debugging with a shared screen.)

Comment: Yep, it's D7. modules/field/field.module exist and it exist as the same Linux user as the user Drush is being run on. I've even tried drush as the Linux root user and that didn't work either. I might contact you again if I need help, I greatly appreciate the attempt.

Comment: I'm sure I can get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ownership of the some of the files in the `sites` directory seems to have fixed the issue.